# Binding directly to an object property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm still getting the hang of WPF and data binding is painful. I want this textbox to bind to the Name property of the page's Exam object.

The following is how I'm usually doing it.

```xml
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="CreateExamStackPanel">
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}" Tag="Exam Name" 
                     x:Name="NameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

```cs
    public partial class CreateExam : Page {
        public CreateExam() {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateExamStackPanel.DataContext = Exam;
        }

        private void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (Exam.Name?.Length > 0)
                MessageBox.Show($"Exam named: {Exam.Name}");
            else
                MessageBox.Show($"Please enter a name for the exam.");
        }

        public Exam Exam { get; set; } = new Exam();
    }
```

But it seems to me that there "should" be a way to bind to the `Exam` entirely through the XAML. 
The `{Binding Path=Name}` points to the property of the `Exam`, but is there a way to point directly to the `Exam` itself?

I've tried adding `{Binding Exam}` to both the `StackPanel` and the `TextBox` in the XAML (and removing the `.DataContext = Exam` from the C# but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit, I'm not actually sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes you can, Text="{Binding}" will bind to the Exam it self. But what you lack here is the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need the entire properties in the CreateExam to the Page right?

If that's the case you can do like

```
public CreateExam()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = this;
 }
```

In your XAML you can bind like

```
     <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="CreateExamStackPanel">
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}" Tag="Exam Name" 
                 x:Name="NameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Exam.Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

or If you need whole Exam as DataContext in your Page then

```
public CreateExam()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = Exam;
 }
```

then your XAML looks like

```
 <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="CreateExamStackPanel">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}" Tag="Exam Name" 
             x:Name="NameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Let me know which one is the case you need so I can remove the other one.

Comment: Thanks. I like that first one a lot, but I'd suggest you keep both because they're both good options.

Comment: ok, I will be keeping both.